# Missing TaskCache class in .NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, custom-model-binder

I have created a Custom Model Binder in .NET Core 1.x . It works well as shown in  the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding).

Once updated to 2.0, I can't compile it anymore. In the old version it was

```
return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
```

Now the `TaskCache` static class isn't available anymore.

Does any know a workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TaskCache.CompletedTask` was [removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/issues/238) in .Net Core 2. Instead just use `Task.CompletedTask`.